# How to select mutiple songs from iTunes on Mac with Windows keyboard?

Tags: itunes, windows

Why I have a Windows keyboard for a Mac mini, I have no idea. But I know that my key that would open the Start menu on windows is Control... yeah. Anyways help me with this pleez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select a continuous grouping you select the first one and then press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, then click the last one in the group.  To select a random grouping you select the first one and then press and hold the <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> key (on a Mac keyboard) or <kbd>Windows</kbd> key (on a Windows keyboard on a Mac), then click the next one and so on until all are selected.  You can let up on the <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> key or <kbd>Windows</kbd> key in-between selecting however make sure you press it before selecting the next one or it will break the grouping and you'd have to start over.

You can deselect by pressing the <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> key or <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, then click the one(s) to be removed.